# REST - different response from same resource dependent on requester

Tags: rest

Let's say I have a single resource of **employee** that belongs to **user**:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "userId: 1
}
```

When making a GET request to /employees/1, I'm using a JWT which contains the userId.

**Any** user can fetch this record regardless of their userId (as long as they're authenticated), however, I want to indicate that the requester actually owns that employee.

I was thinking that on the server I could do an "if (employee.userId === jwt.userId)" and add the result as a property in the result like so:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "userId: 1,
  "isOwner": true
}
```

Does this break REST principles as the same resource will return different results depending on the user making the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

As long as the concept behind the URI is the same (some gray area of course) the server is free to return different *representations* of the same thing best suited for the client or the user making the request.

The same way the resource at amazon.com will return a slightly different page for me than for you.